# How to iterate over a list of object and retrieve each value in XSL?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Suppose you have :

```
Class Employee{
int emp_id; // the employee id
List<Address> adressList; //address list
}

Class Address{
string city;
string country;

}
```

when we iterate through ***addressList***  in the xsl

```
 <xsl:for-each select="employee/adressList">  
                                    
 <xsl:value-of select="employee/adressList/city" />
 <xsl:value-of select="employee/adressList/country" />

 </xsl:for-each>
```

This does not retrieve the each of attributes  value's stored in the list of object.

Is there a way to access each of the attributes inside the list of objects in XSL v1.0?

Can some one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how the classes are mapped to XML but `for-each` changes the context node so inside you probably want relative expressions like

```
<xsl:for-each select="employee/adressList">  
                                    
 <xsl:value-of select="city" />
 <xsl:value-of select="country" />

</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Hey martin, The employee class has an object called employee, through which you can access the employee id and the address list. 

I have used the same code , but im not able retrieve each values in the address list.

Comment: @Vighnesh, I kind of forgot to change the code to use relative paths.